# Wrapping C++ classes that contain wxString with Cython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, cython

I'm working on a Python extension to tie in with a C++ application written using wxWidgets for the GUI. I'm using Cython, and have the basic system (build tools, plus a starter extension with appropriate version details etc) happily working.

I'm only interested in making backend (non-GUI) functionality available, such as file parsing and processing. However, all classes - not just the GUI ones - use `wxString` for string data, such as in the following minimal example:

```
#include <wx/string.h>

class MyClass{
    wxString name;
    wxString get_name(){
        return this->name;
    }
};
```

My question is what is the best way to go about wrapping such a class? Is there a simple way to interface between a Python string and a `wxString` instance? Or will I need to wrap the `wxString` class as well? Am I able to tie in somehow with the wxPython port to avoid re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by using the static `wxString::FromUTF8()` function to convert from Python to wxString, and the `wxString.ToUTF8()` to go in the other direction. The following is the code I came up with:

```
# Import the parts of wxString we want to use.
cdef extern from "wx/string.h":
    cdef cppclass wxString:
        char* ToUTF8()


# Import useful static functions from the class.
cdef extern from "wx/string.h" namespace "wxString":
   wxString FromUTF8(char*)


# Function to convert from Python string to wxString. This can be given either
# a unicode string, or a UTF-8 encoded byte string. Results with other encodings
# are undefined and will probably lead to errors.
cdef inline wxString from_python(python_string):
    # If it is a Python unicode string, encode it to a UTF-8 byte string as this
    # is how we will pass it to wxString.
    if isinstance(python_string, unicode):
        byte_string = python_string.encode('UTF-8')

    # It is already a byte string, and we have no choice but to assume its valid
    # UTF-8 as theres no (sane/efficient) way to detect the encoding.
    else:
        byte_string = python_string

    # Turn the byte string (which is still a Python object) into a C-level char*
    # string.
    cdef char* c_string = byte_string

    # Use the static wxString::FromUTF8() function to get us a wxString.
    return FromUTF8(c_string)


# Function to convert a wxString to a UTF-8 encoded Python byte string.
cdef inline object to_python_utf8(wxString wx_string):
    return wx_string.ToUTF8()


# Function to convert a wxString to a Python unicode string.
cdef inline object to_python_unicode(wxString wx_string):
    # Since the wxString.ToUTF8() method returns a const char*, we'd have to try
    # and cast it if we wanted to do it all in here. I've tried this and can't
    # seem to get it to work. But calling the to_python_utf8() function
    # means Cython handles the conversions and it all just works. Plus, since
    # they are defined as inline functions this may well be simplified down when
    # compiled.
    byte_string = to_python_utf8(wx_string)

    # Decode it to a unicode string and we're done.
    return byte_string.decode('UTF-8')
```

Simply put this in a .pxd file (personally, I put it in a subdirectory as `wx/string.pxd` - make sure you also create an `wx/__init__.pdx` if you choose to do the same). Then `cimport` it and call the functions as appropriate:

```
cimport wx.string

wx_string = wx.string.from_python(python_string)
python_string = wx.string.to_python_unicode(wx_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first approach I would try is to use the wxString constructor:

```
wxString(const wxChar* psz, size_t nLength = wxSTRING_MAXLEN)
```

and pass the const char* string to it to create the object.

Then write some inline functions to convert from python string to wxString and vice versa.

```
PyObject* PyString_FromStringAndSize(const char *v, Py_ssize_t len)
```

Now the only downside I see is that the string might be duplicate in wxString and python world.

A Second Approach would be to subclass wxString and hand reimplement all the operations in a way that uses the Python's PyString Object character buffer. Cython can help in coding such subclass.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It put me on the right track to getting this to work. I've posted my code as a separate answer.